# How to create percentage meter with arc shape and with moving needle in android sdk using layout

Tags: android

```
SeekBar s = new SeekBar(MainActivity.this);
s.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(400, 200));
r1.addView(s);
```

Comment: What do you exactly need? Post snapshot.

Comment: Hello Piyush Gupta, I know some library for seekbar but i want to create a view of half circle which is fill with color with % value.

Comment: Refer this http://device-manual.blogspot.in/2012/12/perform-custom-progressbar-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't attain arc shape using the default seekbar. There are two way to achieve it.

1. You have to customize seekbar according to your need. Refer [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884904/custom-made-arc-shaped-seekbar)
2. Use customized libraries like [this.](http://devadvance.com/circularseekbar/)

All the best!

Comment: Hello Dhasneem, I know some library for seekbar but i want to create a view of half circle which is fill with color with % value.

Comment: Edit your question with detailed explanation